# How do I set the windows system clock to the right local time using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, systemtime

Right now I do something like this:

```
    SYSTEMTIME st;

    st.wHour = 6;
    st.wMinute = 23;

    BOOL result = SetSystemTime(&st);
```

The goal is to get it to show that exact time on my local machine. When I run the program it changes it to 8:23 instead of 6:23. How can I get it to show the correct local time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetSystemTime()` expects the provided time to be in UTC.  If you want to set the time using the local time, use [`SetLocalTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724936(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks this worked. I needed to also use GetLocalTime(&st) first then modify that before I make the call to SetLocalTime(&st). Muchas gracias